# How do I fix: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'AgoraRtcChannelModule.prefix')?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, agora.io

Every time that I import RtcEngine into my application (`import RtcEngine from 'react-native-agora';`) I get the following error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'AgoraRtcChannelModule.prefix')
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:288:29 in invoke
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:152:27 in invoke
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:162:18 in Promise.resolve.then$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:288:29 in invoke
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:152:27 in invoke
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:162:18 in Promise.resolve.then$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

Note: this is without any calls.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I am fairly new to react-native and javascript so I hope I have provided enough information.

Answer (score 2):

Update:
Expo now supports using native modules without ejecting to the bare wofklow with the use of custom development clients, you can learn more about using them with Agora [here](https://www.agora.io/en/blog/building-a-video-calling-app-using-the-agora-sdk-on-expo-react-native/).

After setting up custom development clients, run your app using `expo run:ios` or `expo run:android`.

Comment: Hi, i am using this "agora-react-native-rtm" package and I am also getting the same error

Comment: After setting up custom development clients, run your app using `expo run:ios` or `expo run:android`.

Comment: I am not using expo, I am using react native cli, I used their example and after fixing many bugs I was able to run it but when I tried the same code in my other project I started getting this error. And after checking the code in a package this prefix is coming from native library code written in an android folder and I think this prefix is not coming. I don't know why it is not coming. maybe We have to add something in an android folder, I am sure what is wrong.

Comment: this prefix is a variable in the agora package and the value is coming from native code. It's working in one and not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not using React Native properly.

I'd probably suggest reading the docs and trying the latest version:

- [QuickStart Guide](https://www.agora.io/en/blog/how-to-build-a-react-native-video-calling-app-using-agora/)

P.S: Agora React-Native SDK doesn't support Expo.